# Github Codespaces start terminals with command on startup

Tags: github, terminal, codespaces

does anyone know a way to configure Github codespaces to run automatic multiple terminals with commands (eg. "npm start") on startup?

I already tried the VS-Code extension "Terminal Manager" with configured terminals.json file, but it works just in normal VS-Code. Not in Codespaces.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `postCreateCommand`

> This command is the last of three that finalizes container setup when a dev container is created.

If you have one script you can run after container created with this syntax:

```js
{
  "postCreateCommand": "npm start"
}

// or

{
  "postCreateCommand": ["npm", "start"]
}
```

if you have multiply command you can separate commands with `&&`:

```js
{
  "postCreateCommand": "npm install && npm start"
}
```

[Devcontainer refernce](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference)
[Devcontainer Lifecycle scripts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_lifecycle-scripts)
[String vs array in devcontainer.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_formatting-string-vs-array-properties)
[Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/349#issuecomment-493615638)